# How can I prevent Bootstrap Navbar from stacking the brand on top of the menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've customized a basic Bootstrap navbar - that's about all I'm really using for a project, to not collapse when shrunk. However, whenever the menu is put into a smaller window, it seems to place the brand on top of the menu itself. 
[image]

There will be enough space to not worry about this with the actual menu, so I'd like to figure out how to prevent it from doing this - here is the related script:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!--/.container-fluid -->
```

And my applied CSS for it at the moment:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right!important;
}

.container-fluid {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div class="navbar-header">` is a block, just move `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>` into navbar block.

```
.navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```css
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li,
.navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below markup just below of `<div class="container-fluid">` in your html.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
```

Below is working fiddle for the same

**[Responsive navigation with bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/v8o3j7wf/13/)**